# Ширина контейнера в Bootstrap 2

Tags: bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap 2 (привык я к нему, да и переучиваться на 3 некогда).
Верстал и не знал проблем, как вдруг мне понадобилось сверстать макет с шириной рабочей области не 940/960 как обычно, а 1200px. Попытки в тупую переназначить в своём `style.css` `width:1200px` привели к тому, что всё сместилось влево, а `<span>` не растянулись.
Раньше это можно было сделать через конструктор на сайте, но сейчас там можно скомпилить только под третий Bootstrap.
Повторюсь, я хочу использовать второй. Возможно позже перейду и на 3, но сейчас нужен именно второй.
Насколько я понимаю, придётся компилить его заново из исходников через LESS.
До этого не пользовался никогда им, но если другого выхода нет, так что же - начну.

P.S. Если у кого есть уже переделанные исходники Bootstrap под 1200, поделитесь.
Нужен обычный Bootstrap, но с шириной в 1200.

Comment: @Pavel47, сложные вещи (в том числе бутстрап) на чистом CSS уже не пишутся, для этого используется sass/less. Вам нужно где-то надыбать исходники второго бутстрапа (а лучше все-таки не прятаться за отмазками и ознакомиться с третьим), поменять пару переменных и скомпилировать новую версию.

Comment: Исходники нашел. Но осталось только пнять что именно нужно поменять и где... 
З.Ы. У меня фксированный макет (т.е. адаптивность не нужна).

Comment: @Pavel47, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [файл bootstrap-responsive.css](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css), там есть все изменения сетки под ширину браузера 1200, они находятся внутри блоков `@media (min-width: 1200px)`, можно взять их как основные, и тогда сайт будет 1200px шириной.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как на bootstrap 2, я им почти не пользовался, а на 3 я указывал контейнеру `style="width: 1200px!important"`, и весь шаблон верстал на `col-xs-`.

Comment: у bootstrap 3 сетка в %, поэтому неудивительно.

Comment: тогда я бы всё-таки я посоветовал вам переходить на 3 версию, на неё легко переходить,

Comment: Спасибо, ребят, за идеи) Буду пробовать. Начну с версии с responsive.css, а там как пойдёт. Про третью версию уже действительно ни раз приходила мысль) За ссылку на костамайзер спасибо огромное. Сейчас буду пробовать всё-таки на втором, если до вечера не придумаю решения, то буду переучиваться на третий) 
Еще раз всем спасибо, тему можно закрывать)